# Possible mistake at Nakahara: $F_{\mu\nu}$ vanishing for a particular $A_\mu$

Tags: field-theory, yang-mills, gauge

In equation $(1.293)$ of Nakahara's Geometry, Topology and Physics, he says that the Yang-Mills field tensor $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu+g[A_\mu,A_\nu]$ for a gauge field
$$A_\mu= iU(x)^{-1}\partial_\mu U(x)\tag{1.293}$$
vanishes. However, I can only see that if I replace the $i$ factor with $g^{-1}$ (in that case it would be pure gauge). Did he want to mean that, or does $F_{\mu\nu}$ actually vanish for $(1.293)$?

Comment: section 10.5.5 of the same book expands on that...

Comment: yes, there's a missing factor of $g^{-1}$. It should be $A_\mu = \frac{1}{g} U^{-1} \partial_\mu U$.